# Convert unicode hex back to character

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding

Not sure I have all of my encoding my jargon down right, but...

Let's say you have a character string and you want to replace the non-latin1 characters with its representation in bytes. You do this:

```
a <- "It’s weird calling a place home when you moved a lot as a kid"
iconv(tweets$text, from = "UTF-8", to = "latin1", sub = "byte")
```

And get this:

`[1] It<e2><80><99>s weird calling a place home when you moved a lot as a kid`

Now I want to convert that string *back* from its encoded version, and in essence return the same string that you had originally. How do you do that?

Comment: That's not possible in general.  How would you know that your original string didn't contain "<e2><80><99>"?  If you're willing to assume that, then do the following:  split the string into characters, convert the ones that aren't hex, convert again to raw, put the hex into the raw, convert back to a string.  Lots of work for a questionable result.